# Sink Drain Building Pressure

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, sink, clog

I live on the bottom floor of a 2 unit condo (neighbors above) and the bathroom sink seems to build up pressure in its drain and begin leaking at the tailpiece connection above the p-trap (which is a fairly uncommon place to leak since normally there would not be significant pressure or sitting water at this level AFAIK)

One time while I was gone for a couple weeks I came back and found it leaking and also clearly some dried residue from possibly the upstair neighbors garbage disposal in my sink - indicating that it had backed up. I had a plumber come out and he found a cracked pipe with a clog in it in the basement that he replaced, and that seemed to do the trick, but recently the problem has happened again and is again building pressure enough to slowly leak.

I had another plumber come out who snaked it again for a couple hours and wasn't able to solve it. He was convinced someone poured grout down the sink (since the bathroom was recently reno'd) but I don't think this is it, I did the grout and was pretty careful to avoid pouring down the sink from what I remember.

I was going to try one of these drill powered snakes e.g. https://www.homedepot.com/p/RIDGID-Power-Spin-1-4-in-x-25-ft-Hybrid-Drain-Cleaning-Snake-Auger-Manual-or-Cordless-Drill-Operated-Tool-Only-57043/303644607 and see if I have any luck with it but I'm not sure if there is something else I should try. I would've thought this would be easy work for a plumber so I'm a little confused.

Comment: You might not have pour nasty stuff down, but what about upstairs?  I think vent issues might cause problems with proper draining also, so problem might be higher up than down.

Comment: If you have a narrowing/restriction downstream rather than a complete clog, a rapid flow of water (as from a washing machine or dishwasher draining) can back up above that until it has time to fully pass through the narrowed section. Why not use  an inexpensive endoscope camera to look at the inside of the pipes for at least the 10-15 feet past your sink?

Comment: The fact that you are seeing any leakage at your sink tailpiece tells me that it's not quite properly attached or sealed. They are frequently compression connections -- yours may need a bit of tightening or a replacement of the rubber compression ring.

Comment: That makes sense on tightening the connection but my leak detector has been going off for the past few days so it tells me it's not just a temporary issue but ongoing

Comment: I'm not sure what/where your leak detector is detecting - perhaps you could upload a photo? I'm just saying that there likely is not any pressure in your tailpiece but rather a backup which will flow up into your sink once you correct the leak in the tailpiece. You're right that the backup is an ongoing issue, hence the endoscope suggestion -- see what you are dealing with before throwing tools at it.

Comment: a backup should end up in your sink not leaking from your tail piece.  photo of trap assembly would help.